# Alternative to android.graphics.Path?

Tags: android, canvas, cpu-usage

I am drawing path on the Canvas based on the action move, as the user drags the screen I’m triggering

`path.lineTo(x,y)`

and in OnDraw method of canvas I'm drawing using

`canvas.drawPath(path, paint);`

After 20 minutes of continuous playing with this, the app hangs, and CPU load spikes very high and finally app crashes.  In real life deployment of my app there will be a need of tracking for two-three hours.

Is there any alternative to Path? Or any solution so that we can reduce CPU load?

Comment: OpenGL es... I would rather recommend releasing the screen somethimes, and letting android finish the path

Comment: Hey bali182, Can you please elaborate on "releasing the screen somethimes" ?

Comment: few years ago i made a drawing app wich (similar to your concept) enabled the user to draw lines using paths. The main performance peak comes, when you draw a path for really-really long (the user doesn't release the screen, just draws in a single line), and you force the system, to re-draw a single very-very long path every time, the user moves his/her finger. That's why I written "release the screen sometimes". Possible solution for this, is to limit the max length of a path (max points) and start a new one, if it's too long, but probably won't work if you want to analize it as a whole.

Comment: "2-3 hours".. Its a long time, we have also developed a drawing app recently, it also gets slower, or I must say very slower if User draws for a long time..!! One trick which helped in improving performance was "largeHeap=true" in Manifest..

Comment: Just came to my mind: Another thing, that can help out is, whenever the user finishes drawing a certain amount of lines, convert the `Canvas` to a bitmap, and continue drawing on that. (Also won't work, if you need the paths)

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, i'll try to capture the path periodically and convert it into images, i am not doing any intelligence on path, it just draws.

Kanak Sony, I'll try your solution.